# ERROR: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'string' (aka 'char *') from 'int'

Tags: c, cs50

I created an array with 26 letters and I want to assign each elements to their ASCII values like that:

```
ASCII[0] = 65
ASCII[1] = 66
```

I'd already defined `ASCII[0]` as "A" in my array. So the result that I hope should be:

```
A = 65
B = 66
```

So what is the problem?Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 26

int main(void)
{
    string ASCII[SIZE] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        ASCII[i] = i+65;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'A' is a character. "A" is an array of 1 character (plus a null terminator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you've bitten by the stupid `string` typedef of the CS50 course. In `cs50.h`, `string` is a typedef for *pointer to `char`*. Ordinarily we do not use such a typedef at all in C - there is a lengthy debate about it in the [libcs50 issues](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/163).

The `i + 65` you do there is number, not a pointer - in this case, for a single character.

What you want is *either*:

```
char ASCII[SIZE] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

or

```
char ASCII[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++) {
    ASCII[i] = i + 65; // or even better: i + 'A'
}
```

*either* one will have any element of the 26-character array `ASCII[i]` equal to `65 + i`.

Comment: Yes it works!So it's just about CS50,thank you so much.